# Redshift tuning join

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift, query-performance

I'm trying to join two tables in redshift. One big and one small. The join is by their id, and I've distributed the big one on the cluster by the column (used for the join) and I used as sortkey this column too. The small one table I have distributed whole on all nodes and used sortkey with the column used for the join.

Example:

```
create table table_small diststyle all SORTKEY(id) as select * from another_small_table;

create table big_table distkey (id) diststyle key SORTKEY(id) as SELECT * from another_big_table;

explain SELECT * FROM big_table big JOIN small_table small ON big.id = small.id;
```

The query plan say that redshift is doing a Hash join instead of merge join. This is the expected behaviour? I expected merge join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-the-query-plan.html

> Merge Join
>
> Typically the fastest join, a merge join is used for inner joins and
>   outer joins. The merge join is not used for full joins. This operator
>   is used when joining tables where the join columns are both
>   distribution keys and sort keys, and when less than 20 percent of the
>   joining tables are unsorted. It reads two sorted tables in order and
>   finds the matching rows. To view the percent of unsorted rows, query
>   the SVV_TABLE_INFO system table.

So - as you do not have distribution key of (id) then this join type will not be used.

Comment: I'm using diststyle all on a small table , and diststyle key on a big. My idea is to distribute the big across cluster and the small entire for each node...

Comment: try the same dist for both tables and also just check the unsorted %. merge join does work in proper cases.

Comment: out of curiosity - how much faster is it now?

Comment: it does't performance good. We expected a very fast join :-), but it is very slow...

Comment: can you share your sizings? number of rows on each approx, how many redshift nodes and how fast does it go?

Comment: 3 Redshift nodes,
big_table = 7000000 rows (1.5GB),
small_table = 3000  rows,
time = 1min 43 sec.

Comment: are tables vacuumed and statistics built after the insert? also, select * will be slow anyway if there are many columns in the tables. The problem is not the join but actually returning select star results. Can you try an aggregation query on this join? this is going to be fast

Comment: Yes, you are right! The problem is than we are trining to scan all columns in the table. We will start to see how to filter or choose exactly that we want to search, and maybe the solution is some agregations ...

Comment: @vlarios the point is that you should try count(*) or similar ( an aggregate function) to test whether your long query time is actually related to retrieval of the results. (e.g. network)